# pubnub: The DOM element's value change, but the visual do not change

Tags: jquery, html, pubnub

I am creating a test app on Android phone, which gets json data via ajax from rails server. 
I have set up the real time push functionality between rails and the android phone with PUBNUB. The rails server is the publisher and the android phone is the subscriber.

Issues: 
The phone gets the real time data in the form of json. But, the issue is I cannot do `multiple DOM manipulation INSIDE THE PUBNUB success callback`. This seems absolutely weird.

**What should happen when there is a real time update.**

Background:

1. I have a header image, a ui-bar, content area and a footer.
2. In the UI-Bar has a notification image. If there is any new offer, then it should light into green else it stays red.

**What should happen**

So, there is any new offer pushed in real time, the new offer should be prepended in the list and the notification image should light into green.

**What actually happend**

`Scenario 1`

1. When the content is empty, for the first push, the item gets pushed normally and the notification image turns into green light normally at the same time. I use the json data received from the subscription and use it in the html tags, such as $('#some_id').html('some html tags with data received from subscription');

`Scenario 2`

Say, you acknowledged the notification and it turns back to red. Now, the new scenario is: I have one item pushed already and the notification image is already acknowledged (red light).

1. Now, when the second item is pushed, the item gets pushed normally, but the notification image does not turn into green light. It will only turn into green light if you press anywhere in the screen area.

`Scenario 3`

With the same scenario as num 2 i.e. one offer in the list and notification already been acknowledged.

1. The user will be able to see the green light only after 4 next real time pushes, i.e. 5 all together in the list. The fifth one touches the footer in the phone. After that the real time update functions properly; prepends the item into the list and the notification image turns green on every push (if it was red earlier).

`Scenario 4`

1. If you do not try to push to the list anything, but test only if the notification image is functioning properly on every successful push, it works absolutely fine.

`TEST`

On scenario 2,
I put alert statement to see the notification image before and after the DOM manipulation. The alert statements show changes in values, but `the visual does not change`.

```
 alert($('#home_notification').html());
 $('#home_notification').html('<img alt="Greenlight" height="31px" src="css/images/greenlight.png" class="notification_img" width="35px">'); 
 alert($('#home_notification').html());
```

Below is the my script tag snippet from the html page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   PUBNUB.subscribe({
    channel    : "rails",      // CONNECT TO THIS CHANNEL.
    restore    : false,              // STAY CONNECTED, EVEN WHEN BROWSER IS CLOSED
                                     // OR WHEN PAGE CHANGES.
    callback   : function(message) { // RECEIVED A MESSAGE.
            var month=new Array();
            month[0]="Jan";
            month[1]="Feb";
            month[2]="Mar";
            month[3]="Apr";
            month[4]="May";
            month[5]="Jun";
            month[6]="Jul";
            month[7]="Aug";
            month[8]="Sep";
            month[9]="Oct";
            month[10]="Nov";
            month[11]="Dec";


            //***************This is the offer that will get prepended in the list************************* 
            $('#offers_table').prepend('<tbody><tr class="offer_list_unread"><td class="spacer"><img alt="Spacer" src="css/images/spacer.png"></td><td class="image"><img height="60px" src="css/images/' + message['code'] + 'o.png" width="60px"></td><td class="description"><h3>'+ message['description']+ '</h3><p>Start Date: '+ month[(new Date(message["startdate"])).getMonth()] + ' ' + (new Date(message["startdate"])).getDate() +', '+ (new Date(message["startdate"])).getFullYear()  +'</p><p>End Date: '+ month[(new Date(message["enddate"])).getMonth()] + ' ' + (new Date(message["enddate"])).getDate() +', '+ (new Date(message["enddate"])).getFullYear() +'</p></td><td class="mark_as_read"><img alt="Unread1" class="unread" src="css/images/unread1.png"><p class="read" style="display:none">offers/'+message['id']+'</p></td></tr></tbody>');   


            //**************************This is where I have am having issues****************************
            //**************************THIS IS NOT SHOWN IN THE VISUALS AFTER SECOND REAL TIME PUSH********************************
            $('#home_notification').html('<img alt="Greenlight" height="31px" src="css/images/greenlight.png" class="notification_img" width="35px">');
        }


   });
});
```

Comment: We are looking into this now.  I believe we can get this working correctly for you!  :-)

Comment: Can you send us a full html page to our support@pubnub.com email address and then we can get this working for you as expected.

Comment: Thanks @sagarpant. Let me investigate this and get back to you shortly with an update.

Comment: Thank you for the email!  We are looking into this :-)

Comment: Hi @Gemery, PubNub have you found any solution to this issue? Please let me know if you need anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not an issue with PubNub, but with Android.
I've been struggling with the same problem for days and have not found a solution yet.
The symptoms are the same: in a callback (any callback, from an async AJAX request or even from setTimeout), I can update a JavaScript object (and see it), but any updates to the DOM are just ignored. 
What is interesting, if I use a synchronous AJAX request, then the DOM updates get executed in the jQuery AJAX callback. What is more interesting, if I use setTimeout inside the synchronous AJAX callback (just for testing), then the DOM updates are not executed in the setTimeout callback.
So, for some reason, the stock Android browser does not like updating DOM in any asynchronous callbacks. If the executing is sequential (as with synchronous AJAX), the DOM gets updated.
I was testing on Samsung G2 with Android 4.0. The same code is working fine in any desktop browser and on iOS (using PhoneGap), but does not work on Android (using PhoneGap).

Would be interesting to hear what other people think about this.